# Hyperledger Test Network not running

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, dlt

I am trying to install hyperledger fabric.
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html
I installed the prerequisites.
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test_network.html

When I start the test network, I get the following error:

username:~/hyperledger/fabric-samples/test-network$ ./network.sh up
Starting nodes with CLI timeout of '5' tries and CLI delay of '3' seconds and using database 'leveldb' with crypto from 'cryptogen'
Peer binary and configuration files not found..
Follow the instructions in the Fabric docs to install the Fabric Binaries:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

I was trying this on Ubuntu 22.04 and Mac OS both.

I have tried several other links and youtube videos, nothing works. There is a problem cloning the script and binaries I think.

I just want to run the test network and chaincode testing after that to make applications on Hyperledger

Answer (score 0):

After trying for few days, I was able to install hyperledger successfully on Ubuntu 22.04.

Here is the main step to download fabric samples:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s
```

The bitly link was flagged. Hope this helps the people struggling with hyperledger.